# Is there a browser that Ctrl+W does not close tab?

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

There is enough discussion on how both Firefox and Chrome dominate what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does: Closes the current tab. And how it is not configurable/overridable.

This question is asking for alternative software. Does there exist a browser where pressing the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does not close the current tab?

I am Windows and Linux.

Comment: Why??? It's the universal shortcut for "Close", not just in browsers & not just on Windows.

Comment: It's the same combination as the `copy` action in Emacs. I've lost so much work accidentally closing tabs because of this muscle memory trigger. I'm willing to loose these browser.

And since when it became the _universal_ for "Close"?

Comment: Found some history on Ctrl+W https://superuser.com/questions/721645/whats-the-logic-behind-the-w-in-controlw-to-close-a-tab-in-ie/721652

Comment: It's 'universal' because it was adopted by almost everyone back in the 80s. Emacs predates this universal acceptance (though GNU Emacs is 91, so that was their time to reconsider, historically;), but maybe they should have gone with the flow rather than fought it. I do recall Atari in 87 or so giving up their previously-chosen commands & 'going with the flow'… & being annoyed that copy/cut/paste/undo became some unfathomable ctrl/c, x, v, z. In the 30-odd years since then I just got the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Vivaldi for this. Vivaldi is a Chrome based browser, but in the settings, there is a keyboard tab where you can define every keyboard shorcut you wish to use (or in this case, not use).

In the TAB section, Close tab is set to both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but if you hover your mouse on that row, an <kbd>x</kbd> appears at the right which you can use to clear the shortcut.

Comment: To whoever vote us down. Please explain why....

Comment: Maybe the wine shop isn't open yet… or maybe it opened 8 hours ago… who can tell.;)

Comment: Thanks for recommending Vivaldi. It should be pointed out that Vivaldi is proprietary software. Never the less, it does allow keyboard-shortcut customization!. I have switch-off Ctrl+W, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+B and now all those online editors that emulate Emacs, do emulate Emacs! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't get your comment? Vivaldi is available on all major OSses, including linux

Comment: I never mentioned Vivaldi - I was commenting on "why the downvote?" To much or too little alcohol was my theory ;))

Comment: +1 : With my compliments.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah. :) gotcha. I read wine as: vivaldi is not for linux, so you need wine to run it... I guess I'm too much of a nerd. lol

Comment: @harrymc thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You may block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> on any browser using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Use the following example script for Chrome:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2        ; title can contain string anywhere to match
#IfWinActive, Chrome        ; title contains "Chrome"
^w::return                  ; ignore Ctrl-W
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [WinActive() / IfWin[Not]Active](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)

Comment: +1 because this definitely does NOT deserver a -1

Comment: in Windows it's easier to use PowerToys: https://superuser.com/questions/543971/how-to-change-the-windows-alttab-hotkey-to-something-else/1588228#1588228

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to a shortcut that does nothing in your system. The way to do it depends on the desktop environment of your choice.

For example, if you're using the GNOME desktop environment on a Linux distribution you can follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings; → *Keyboard* → *View and Customize Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts* and click the <kbd>+</kbd> icon:

   [image: Custom Shortcuts window]
2. On the window that opens enter the following:

   - *Name*: `Disable Ctrl+W` (you may select another name if you wish)
   - *Command*: Leave empty
   - *Shortcut*: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

   [image: Add Custom Shortcut window]
3. Click *Add* on the top right of the window.

That's it! The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut should now be disabled. Mind though that this approach disables this shortcut in general, so you won't be able to use it in another program. If your workflow in another program depends on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut, please don't use this approach.

For Windows, you can follow a similar procedure to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut by using the [Power Toys Keyboard Manager utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager).

---

I just saw in a [comment of yours](https://superuser.com/questions/1620356/is-there-a-browser-that-ctrlw-does-not-close-tab#comment2472591_1620356) that you want to disable this keyboard shortcut because you are used to the Emacs shortcut for copying a file. Instead of dropping a browser just for that, you could also change the keyboard shortcut for copying a file in Emacs.

Based on [How to change keyboard shortcuts for copy, cut and paste and set keyboard shortcut for debugger (GDB)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/27291), you can add the following line in your `.emacs` file to set the shortcut to save a file to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the common copy shortcut (or whatever you prefer):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)
```

---

In [your comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1620356/is-there-a-browser-that-ctrlw-does-not-close-tab#comment2472591_1620356) you also state that:

> [...] I've lost so much work accidentally closing tabs because of this muscle memory trigger. [...]

I would like to remind you in that case that you can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut in your browser to reopen your closed tabs in a recently closed sequence.

Comment: Thanks for these workarounds at the OS/System level. It may be handy for someone. I do like the Emacs way of doing things and would never change it. I still want to be able to do C-w in Emacs, so disabling it a lower level is not acceptable. I don't mind if I need to do things a bit differently in other software but closing tabs is too destructive. Reopening closed tabs does not restore entered content, i.e. in forms etc.