# Is there a key combination that mimics the Windows key?

Tags: windows-11, hotkeys

I"m trying to assign a hotkey to a program (Snagit v2019)
Snagit only gives me the choice so <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and a key for assigning as a hotkey.

I want to choose <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd>

But <kbd>Windows</kbd> isn't a choice (in Snagit)

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find Windows keyboard scancode registry information?](https://superuser.com/questions/550679/where-can-i-find-windows-keyboard-scancode-registry-information)

Comment: CTRL + ESC opens the Start Menu the same way you would by pressing the WIN key, but CTRL + ESC + X does not behave the same way WIN + X does, so it's a limited comparison. However, your question's title and body don't seem to line up precisely. "Mimic" means to copy, more or  less, so your title is asking for a key combination that is an alternative to the WIN key. The question body, however, seems to be asking how to use the WIN key in a key combination, but doesn't specify which utility or tool or setting you're trying to use to set such a hotkey. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @music2myear That answers my question:  I had a distant memory that there was another key combination that had the same effect as [Windows] key but I see now that it only mimic'd the effect of pressing the [Windows] key in isolation. So no way to do what I need.

Comment: The question as you've edited it has been answered on this site already. Here's one https://superuser.com/questions/202000/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-custom-hotkey-in-windows-that-will-close-the-current and here's a search that'll have some more helpful specifics https://superuser.com/search?q=autohotkey+win+key

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Registry scancodes to change the action of a key, so that the Windows key will act as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> -- but that would mean you could never use <kbd>Windows</kbd> for its intended purpose, a really *bad* idea!

There are a number of third-party tools, such as [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/?lang=en) and [AutoHotkey](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey) that remap key combinations to an action. Usually, these are *global* keyboard shortcuts, but if <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is not used elsewhere, you could use one of those utilities.

Answer (score 0):

*Turning my comment into an answer, as OP notes this is what they were looking for:*

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> opens the Start Menu the same way you would by pressing the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> does not behave the same way <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> does, so it's a limited comparison.

Your title is asking for a key combination that is an alternative to the WIN key. The question body, however, seems to be asking how to use the WIN key in a key combination, but doesn't specify which utility or tool or setting you're trying to use to set such a hotkey.

Comment: Edited question. I now includes what I'm trying to do and in what app.